# Adicionar array dentro de array

Tags: php

Como adicionar um array dentro de outro array ?
Tenho esses 2, quero adicionar o debaixo no de cima, com o nome de "respostas"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [unidade] => 4
            [exercicio] => 1
            [enunciado] => Complete with the correct pronoun
            [pergunta] => Marcus and his brother talk about politics between ???
            [imagem] => 
            [tipo] => complete1
            [respostacorreta] => themselves
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => They
            [1] => Them
            [2] => Themselves
        )

)
```

Meu resultado final em json deve ficar algo como:

```
    {
    "0": {
        "id": "0",
        "unidade": "4",
        "exercicio": "1",
        "enunciado": "Complete with the correct pronoun",
        "pergunta": "Marcus and his brother talk about politics between ???",
        "imagem": null,
        "tipo": "complete1",
        "respostas": [
                      "They",
                      "Them",
                      "Themselves"
                  ],
        "respostacorreta": "themselves"
    }
}
```

Meu código atual ta assim:

```
$sql = new Sql();
$exercicioarray = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_exercicios");
$arrayrespostas = explode(',',$exercicioarray[0]['respostas']);
unset($exercicioarray[0]['respostas']);
$exercicioarraysemresposta = $exercicioarray;
$exercicioarraycomresposta = $exercicioarraysemresposta[$exercicioarraysemresposta[0]['respostas']] = $arrayrespostas;



//print_r($exercicioarraysemresposta);
//print_r($arrayrespostas);

$response = json_encode($exercicioarraysemresposta, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez fosse melhor você retornar tudo na mesma consulta SQL, mas como não tenho detalhes do seu banco de dados não da para fazer dessa maneira.

Você tem alguns equivocos no seu codigo. Geralmente para adicinar novos elementos em um array usa-se a seguinte sintaxe:

```
//vazio
$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];

//para adicionar elementos com indice numerico
$array1[] = 1;
$array1[] = 2;
$array1[] = 3;

//no final $array1 = [1, 2, 3]

//para adicionar elementos com chave
$array2['campo1'] = 1;
$array2['campo2'] = 2;
$array2['campo3'] = 3;

//$array2 = ['campo1' => 1, 'campo2' => 2, 'campo3' => 3]
```

Aplicando ao seu codigo fica:

```
//se estiver na mesma linha da proxima instrução, 
//só o array respostas será copiado
$exercicioarraysemresposta[0]['respostas'] = $arrayrespostas;
$exercicioarraycomresposta = $exercicioarraysemresposta;
```

Um teste mais completo:

```
<?php
 $exercicioarraysemresposta = [
     [
         'id' => 0,
         'unidade' => 4,
         'exercicio' => 1,
         'enunciado' => 'Complete with the correct pronoun',
         'pergunta' => 'Marcus and his brother talk about politics between ???',
         'imagem' => null,
         'tipo' => 'complete1',
         'respostacorreta' => 'themselves'
     ]
 ];

$arrayrespostas = [
    'They',
    'Them',
    'Themselves'
];

//se estiver na mesma linha da proxima instrução, só o array respostas será copiado
$exercicioarraysemresposta[0]['respostas'] = $arrayrespostas;
$exercicioarraycomresposta = $exercicioarraysemresposta;

var_dump($exercicioarraycomresposta);

echo json_encode($exercicioarraycomresposta);

?>
```

Gera como saida json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "unidade": 4,
    "exercicio": 1,
    "enunciado": "Complete with the correct pronoun",
    "pergunta": "Marcus and his brother talk about politics between ???",
    "imagem": null,
    "tipo": "complete1",
    "respostacorreta": "themselves",
    "respostas": [
      "They",
      "Them",
      "Themselves"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado. acho que entendi a lógica, o problema agora é tratar esse index do array, pois o banco vai me retornar varios arrays desses. mas ja tenho uma ideia com loop

Comment: como seria retornar tudo na mesma consulta SQL? meu banco esta estruturado do jeito q o json final fica com um porem de que as respostas é um string separada por virgulas

Comment: @IgorOliveira Com base nessas novas informações, você só precisa do `$exercicioarray`. Basicamente deixe de fazer o `unset` e no lugar faça `$exercicioarray[0]['respostas'] = $arrayrespostas;`. Que fica melhor para iterar em um loop, algo como `for($i=0; $i < count($arrayrespostas); $i++) $exercicioarray[$i]['respostas'] = explode(',',$exercicioarray[$i]['respostas']);`

Comment: Muito bom, exatamente oque precisava, Obrigado Juven_v

Answer (score 0):

troque

```
$exercicioarraycomresposta = $exercicioarraysemresposta[$exercicioarraysemresposta[0]['respostas']] = $arrayrespostas;
```

por

```
 $exercicioarraycomresposta = $exercicioarraysemresposta;
 $exercicioarraycomresposta[0]['resposta'] = $arrayrespostas;
```

Comment: ele criou outro array, não ficou dentro do array 0

Comment: Editei e agora não cria mais um novo